# When did the last wizarding war happen before "The Crimes of Grindelwald"?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

The new Crimes of Grindelwald trailer states

> The wizarding and non-wizarding world have been at peace for over a century

Implying that previously there wasn't peace.

When was the last wizarding war before this, and is it mentioned any where else in the Harry Potter universe?

Comment: maybe it's a reference to the upcoming game which is reportedly set in the 1800's

Answer (score 6):

## Its unclear.

This statement may not be referring to a wizarding war at all. Since we cant be sure when the Global Wizarding war started (Grindelwald's war) it makes it a little harder to approximate what the date for a century before, but we do know it ended in 1945. One big event that happens around a century previously (if you take away 20-25 years from 1945) is the enforcement of Rappaport's law which was created in 1790.

> One of the most significant American magical laws was created in 1790, when MACUSA approved an edict to enforce total segregation of the wizarding and No-Maj communities. Rappaport’s Law, named after then-President Emily Rappaport, was created as a result of one of the worst breaches of the International Statute of Secrecy ever known, a breach in which the daughter of Rappaport’s Keeper of Treasure and Dragots and a Scourer descendant almost exposed the existence of magic worldwide. With the passing of Rappaport’s Law, intermarriage and even friendship between wizards and No-Majs became illegal in the United States.
> <sub><sup>*- [The Magical Congress of the United States of America - Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa)*</sup></sub>

To the wizarding population this may have symbolized an era of peace, because before this America was a pretty hostile environment for Witches and Wizards.

> America remained one of the most hostile environments for magical people, mainly because of Scourer descendants who had vanished permanently into the No-Maj community and who kept suspicion of magic alive. Unlike most Western countries, there was no cooperation between the No-Maj government and MACUSA.
> <sub><sup>*- [The Magical Congress of the United States of America - Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa)*</sup></sub>

But with the complete segregation from the No-Maj community they wouldn't be under their threat.

Answer (score 6):

## We don’t know - no earlier wars have been previously mentioned.

There haven’t been any other things mentioned that would likely be classified as wizarding wars, either among different factions of wizards, or wizards fighting against Muggles. There may have been, and likely were at some point, other wizarding wars, but there’s nothing currently known about them. The only wizarding wars mentioned so far are the ones involving the Dark Lord, and the one involving Grindelwald. No others are known as of yet.

## This may refer to how Dorcus Twelvetrees nearly exposed magic.

Since the imposition of the Statute of Secrecy in 1692, the only mentioned conflict between wizards and Muggles is when Bartholomew Barebone tricked information out of a dimwitted witch named Dorcus Twelvetrees, and used it to attempt to expose the wizarding world. Especially considering Dumbledore said ‘The wizarding and non-wizarding world have been at peace for over a century’ and the movie is set around 1927, this seems likely to be the non-peaceful period that Dumbledore could be referring to - it’s not a war, but it did involve a conflict between wizards and Muggles, and magic was nearly exposed. Bartholomew was the descendant of Scourers, wizards who used to be bounty hunters, and believed both that magic did exist and that everyone who could use it was evil.

> One day, at a local picnic, Dorcus Twelvetrees became greatly enamoured of a handsome No-Maj called Bartholomew Barebone. Unbeknownst to Dorcus, Bartholomew was a Scourer descendant. Nobody in his family was magic, but his belief in magic was profound and unshakeable, as was his conviction that all witches and wizards were evil. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Rappaport’s Law (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/rappaports-law-en)*</sup></sub>

Dorcus ended up telling him a lot of information about the wizarding world, including the locations of MACUSA and Ilvermorny, as well as the ways that the authorities in the wizarding world like the International Confederation of Wizards worked to keep magic hidden from Muggles.

> Totally oblivious to the danger, Dorcus took Bartholomew’s polite interest in her ‘little tricks’ at face value. Led on by her beau’s artless questions, she confided the secret addresses of both MACUSA and Ilvermorny, along with information about the International Confederation of Wizards and all the ways in which these bodies sought to protect and conceal the wizarding community. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Rappaport’s Law (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/rappaports-law-en)*</sup></sub>

When he got this information, Bartholomew took it to the Muggle press (along with the wand he stole from Dorcus). He also gathered together a group of people who set out with the intention of killing all the wizards they could find.

> Having gathered as much information as he could from Dorcus, Bartholomew stole the wand she had obligingly demonstrated for him, showed it to as many pressmen as he could find, then gathered together armed friends and set out to persecute and, ideally, kill all the witches and wizards in the vicinity. Bartholomew further printed leaflets giving the addresses where witches and wizards congregated and sent letters to prominent No-Majs, some of whom felt it necessary to investigate whether there were indeed ‘evil occult parties’ happening at the places described. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Rappaport’s Law (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/rappaports-law-en)*</sup></sub>

Even after the No-Maj government had thrown Bartholomew in jail when he shot at No-Majs thinking they were wizards, a lot of information had gotten out which had to be covered up, and this large violation of the Statute  had seriously affected the wizarding community.

> Bartholomew had disseminated his leaflets widely, and a few newspapers had taken him seriously enough to print pictures of Dorcus’s wand and note that it ‘had a kick like a mule’ if waved. The attention focused on the MACUSA building was so intense that it was forced to move premises. As President Rappaport was forced to tell the International Confederation of Wizards at a public inquiry, she could not be sure that every last person privy to Dorcus’s information had been Obliviated. The leak had been so serious that the after-effects would be felt for many years. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Rappaport’s Law (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/rappaports-law-en)*</sup></sub>

This had far-reaching effects - it caused MACUSA to change its location, and resulted in the creation of a new law, Rappaport’s Law, to prevent wizards fraternizing with Muggles, so they couldn’t leak information like this again. Though it wasn’t a war, it was a period of turmoil between wizards and Muggles, and since the law that was a result of it was created in 1790, the tumultuous time preceding that would have been more than a century before Dumbledore’s statement about over a century of peace between wizards and non-wizards, so the timeframe matches up.